# Using a CSS preprocessors for a novice

Tags: css

I'm kinda novice of crafting CSS and I feel inconvenient a bit while trying to keep it organized. My CSS is now about 800 lines and becomes bigger and bigger. I know that that is not a challenging task for skilled people but for me it is. While searching for good advises on organizing CSS I became aware of CSS preprocessor system such as LESS, SCSS (SASS).

So the question is:
Is it a good way to use them for a novice like me? Or It's better to develop skill of crafting standard CSS and only after that (having understood all the difficulties and hacks there) turn my head to preprocessor system?

Comment: Yes => craft before, then industrialize.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely learn how to do it right from scratch. Later on your 'external toolkit' will be helpful. Otherwise you'll end up with a crutch. That's if for no other reason than having to work with other people's code where your favorite tools are not an option.

Answer (score 2):

I wish I had known about preprocessors earlier. Still, knowing CSS fairly well when I started using preprocessors definitely helped. I would look for ways to break up your CSS as it is for now, and when you feel mildly comfortable, start out with LESS's variables and nesting.

Try dividing up your CSS into multiple files if they can be broken into easily segregated elements, and then combine/minify for the final release build.